# Find specific word outside square brackets?

Tags: regex

I have the following block of text

```
Word1 
Word2 
Word3 
Word4 [Hello world Word1]
```

I need a regex to find Word1 outside the brackets - but not inside the brackets could I do this with regex?

Thanks Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question raises some problems, regarding bracket nesting. I can make up a regex that works on `[...]...[..][...]`, but what about `[[[][]][]]` ? I don't know what language you're using, but if it supports recursive regex, use this: **`/\[([^[]|(?R))*?\]/`**. You need to remove anything matching this regex, and then search the word you need with a standard search function.

Regex explanation:

```
\[       // opening bracket
  (      // start group
  [^[]   // any character, but not opening bracket
  |      // or
  (?R)   // another nested bracket group
  )*?     // zero or more of this group, lazy
\]       // closing bracket
```

Example:

[image: using RegExr]

Comment: we dont have recursive reg ex and im using MS WORD wild cards :( - also how would I find a specific word outside the brackets rather than everything